# Preencher dois inputs automaticamente, utilizando dados de um input e select buscados em banco

Tags: javascript, ajax

estou com um problema, estava desenvolvendo em PHP que já tenho algum conhecimento.
Porém um cliente me solicitou que fizesse um sistema para ele e peguei algo que para mim foi meio inusitado.
O cliente precisa que no formulário de cadastro dele, o usuário que está cadastrando, selecione o estado aonde mora e digite o titulo de eleitor, ao digitar busque estas informações no banco de dados(MySql) e retorne o nome e a cidade do usuário automaticamente ou mande um alert para o usuário acaso não seja encontrado.
E possível fazer isto?
Que linguagem se utilizaria?
Utilizaria linguagem cliente, tipo javascript? Qual seria uma ideia para desenvolver isto?
Obs.: Sempre fui mais voltado a linguagem de programação desktop a linguagem que tenho um bom conhecimento web e só PHP.

Comment: Se vc usa jQuery, basta colocar dentro do arquivo que o Ajax vai chamar um script preenchendo os campos NOME e CIDADE caso eles sejam encontrados; caso não, manda um alert.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Para fazer isso use `Javascript`, ou melhor ainda, uma biblioteca javascript chamada `j-query`, que facilita muito as requisições `Ajax`, exemplo...

**formulário**

```
# Jquery #
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script> 

# Requisição ajax #
<script src="model/ajaxCli.js"></script>

<form name="formCurl" id="env" method="post">

    <label for="inpPesquisa">Pesquise por clientes</label>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Digite o nome" name="termo" required="required">

    <input type="submit">

</form>
```

**ajaxCli.js**

```
$(document).ready(function(){


        $( "#env" ).submit(function( event ) {
         event.preventDefault();

         # pega os dados do formulário #
         var data = $("#env").serialize();

            $.ajax({
                type : "POST",
                # página php onde irá consultar #
                url  : "controller/clientes.php",
                data : data,
                dataType: "json",
                success : function(response){
                    # em caso de sucesso #
                    if (response.codigo == 1) {

          $('tbody').html('<tr><td>' + response.nomeCli + '</td><td>' + response.nomeCat + '</td></tr>');

                    };

                    # em caso de cliente não encontrado #
                    if (response.codigo == 0) {

          alert('Cliente não encontrado');

                    };
                }
            })
        });

    })
```

**clientes.php**

```
<?php
   class getClientes{

    # seu método # ...

if(#sua condição#) {
      $retorno = array('codigo' => 1);
        echo json_encode($retorno);
        exit();
    }
    else {
      $retorno = array('codigo' => 0);
      echo json_encode($retorno);
      exit();
  }

   }
   $execClass = new getClientes();
   $execClass->termo = (isset($_POST['termo']) ? $_POST['termo'] : '');
   $execClass->_getClientes($execClass->termo);
?>
```

Básicamente é isso, basta estudar mais essa função. A propósito, já que vem de desktop, podes trocar a biblioteca `J-query` por uma mais modularizada, exemplo `AngularJs`, mais isso para projetos a médio/longo prazo, pois a curva de aprendizado é maior